# Normal C++ code in Qt doesnt build and run

Tags: c++, qt4

I am using Qt under linux, if it matters.
I ran successfully under Geany (a simple c++ compiler) the following:

```
//my first program in C++ Hello World!
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;}
```

I opened Qt source file and copied the exact same code and i can't build or run.

Thank you for your responses to this simple problem.

Comment: I'm not a mind reader.  seeing the actual compiler errors might help me and others figure out the cause of the problem.

Comment: Where in the Qt project did you copy that code? You probably already have a main() somewhere so don't repeat that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did what I think you did, you didn't open this as a project, which is the only place where you can build and run (I think).

Try the following.
 - Open Qt Creator.
 - Go to File->New File or Project
 - At the bottom, select "Qt4 Console Application"
 - Select a location; it might be nice to create a folder called "hello_world" or something to store the project in.
 - A new project will have been created.  Copy over the main.cpp file in sources with your code.  My code looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hit "Build All"
Hit "Run"

This worked for me.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, i dont get a new window popping up. when i hit "run" this is all i get http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/5808/screenshotghl.png

I also tried to run the .exe file, still nothing happens.
I suppose it is some minor mistake I am making.

Thank you once again

Comment: This code is displaying "Hello World !" into a console and exit. So when you launch it you will see the console appar and disappear immediately.

Comment: So it exits by itself? I dont see it appear and disappear. Probably it happens too fast? 

Can I tell it to stay and exit only when i close the window?

Comment: This particular project won't show a window because it was a console app.  If you want something that uses a GUI, create a Qt4 GUI app instead of a console app and then follow along here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial-t1.html

I'm not sure about the executable; when I run it at the command line it outputs correctly.

Also, a minor note, but you wrote /n instead of \n so it's outputting the full string instead of writing a newline.